# Dynamically passing data to a child component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that is responsible for listing out data and if the user clicks on a particular data item, it renders a popup with the data the user clicked passed to it.  The popup is defined in a separate component but a single instance of the popup is defined in listing component as follows:

```js
render(){
  return(
      ...
      {tasks.map((task, index) => {
        return (
            <p><a onClick={() => self.edit(task.id)}>{task.name}</a></p>
        );
      })}
      <EditTaskPopup show={self.state.showEditPopup} onClose={self.onClosePopup} task={self.state.editData} />
      ...
  )
}
```

The edit function, packages up the data and sets the component's state so that the data in included in the editData variable and the popup is shown as follows:

> ```js
>     self.setState({showEditPopup: true, editData: tasks[x]});
> ```

This all works fine but my question is how I should correctly receive that data in the popup container, EditTaskPopup.  The constructor of EditTaskPopup fire off when the parent component loads, so no user interaction has occurred, so no value is passed in.  Same holds true for componentDidMount.  I can see the correct value being passed in when the componentDidUpdate fires off, but that also fires off during the normal operation of the popup where I'm collecting information about what the user is typing within the popup and placing those values in state.  Is there an event in a component that only fires off when a parent component changes the parameters passed into it but doesn't fire off when state changes within the component itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try utilising lifecycle method: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate